# Parsing "sections" in a configuration file in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, configuration

I am wondering if there is an elegant approach to parsing a typical configuration file in C++.

```
# This is a comment

log =/var/log/secure

max_tries=5

max_reports=2
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
std::string buf;
smatch matches;
int line_number = 0; // keeping track of the line number allows for error identification
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> parsed_options;

while (std::getline(is, buf)) {
    // is the line a comment or blank?
    if ((buf.find_first_of('#') == 0) || (std::all_of(buf.begin(), buf.end(), isspace)) || (buf.empty())) {
    } else {
        std::istringstream configs(buf);
        std::string option;
        if (std::getline(configs, option, '=')) {
            std::string val;
            if (std::getline(configs, val)) {
                option.erase(std::remove_if(option.begin(), option.end(), isspace), option.end());
                val.erase(std::remove_if(val.begin(), val.end(), isspace), val.end());
                parsed_options.emplace(std::make_pair(option, val));
            }

        } else {
            std::stringstream se;
            se << "Coud not parse option at line " << line_number;
            throw std::runtime_error(se.str());
        }
    }
    ++line_number;
}

for (auto i : parsed_options) {
    if (i.first == "log") {
        auth_log_ = i.second;
    } else if (i.first == "max_tries") {
        max_attempts_ = std::stoi(i.second);
    } else if (i.first == "max_reports") {
        max_reports_ = std::stoi(i.second);
    } else if (i.first == "interval") {
        interval_ == std::stoi(i.second);
    } else {
        std::cout << "\"" << i.first << "\" " << i.second << '\n';
        std::stringstream ss1;
        ss1 << "Invalid option at line " << line_number;
        throw std::runtime_error(ss1.str());
    }
}
```

}

While this works, I have an issue. I want to add support for so-called "sections".

```
# This is a comment

[section1]
log =/var/log/secure

max_tries=5

max_reports=2

[section2]
log =/var/log/secure

max_tries=5

max_reports=2
```

Given this configuration file, I would ideally be able parse the sections separately. Eventually I'm going to need it where I can read the section name, and use the options under each section without conflict. If the names under each section matches the names for another, I would need to be able to extract the values from both sections without running into problems. I would prefer not to use Boost seeing as how I prefer STL, but if it proves to much faster and more efficient I will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration file just seems to be a ini?

There's a heap of ini parsers around that will save you the work of writing your own from scratch if that's a option:

- [inih](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih)
- [simpleini](https://github.com/brofield/simpleini)

Comment: Thanks, this turned what seemed like a headache of code into a few simple lines with simpleini